# How to split a row from multiple charactes?

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading a file where the there are multiple rows like:
1,1; 4
1,2; 6
2,4; 12
...

The first two numbers are coordinates x,y and the third number is a value
If I split it from the ";" after rstrip
I get a list
['x,y' ' value']
or if I split it from the ","
I get a list
['x', 'y; value']

How do I split the row in a way that I have three different parameters:
x_coordinate
y_coordinate
value

for example my code looks like this now:

```
file = open(filename, "r")
        for row in file:
            row = row.rstrip()
            parts = row.split(";")
            coordinates = row.split(",")
            x_coordinate = int(coordinates[0])
            y_coordinate = int(coordinates[0][1])
            value = int(parts[3])
            area_list[x_coordinate-1][y_coordinate-1] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use compound pattern for split:

```
import re

with open(filename) as f:
    pat = re.compile(r'[,;]\s*')  # precompiled regex pattern
    for line in f:
        x, y, val = pat.split(line.strip())
        print(x, y, val)
```